# Setting affine transform on NSView layer not working as on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cgaffinetransformscale

I am trying to achieve something very simple. I would like to transform a layer's scale. However it does not seem to work as expected. In fact, it does not work at all. The layer's scale remains the same.

Here is my code:

```
NSView *v = [[NSView alloc]init];
v.wantsLayer = YES;
v.frame = self.bounds;
float scale = 0.8f;
[v.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale,scale)];
[self addSubview:v];
```

If I log the `affineTransform` property of `v` I get `null`.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Guess what? NSView also has layer-backed views which have transforms. Your comment is not helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this on OSX:

```
self.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(scale, scale, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Pass 1 instead of 0 in the sz parameter, or your layer won't get clicks anymore ;)